# how to remove a character from a string with loop?

Tags: c, string, loops

Im trying to make the program remove a character from a string that the user is putting in but i get an error inside the loop. (side question: is adding a character inside the string the "same" code with some small changes?)

PS New to programming...

Comment: `k < str` is highly suspect

Comment: What are the calls for `getchar()` for? It'll remove the first character from each line of input which seems unlikely that is what you want

Comment: Calling `getchar` before `fgets` seems to be wrong. `if (str[k] != ch)` tries to compare a character from `str` with the address of the first character in `ch`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Changes:

- getchar() and fgets() to scanf()
- added strlen() to get length of string
- added lenght of input string to printf
- added zero init of strings

Note: After each input with scanf() you have to press enter.

```
int main()
{      
    char str[100] = { 0 };
    char ch[5] = { 0 };
    int k, j;

    printf("Write text:\n");
    scanf("%s", str);

    printf("Input was: %s\nLength: %d\n", str, strlen(str));

    printf("Write a character that should be removed\n");
    scanf("%s", ch);

    for (k = 0, j = 0; k < strlen(str); k++)
    {
        if (str[k] != ch[0]) {
            str[j] = str[k];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    printf("String after removing a character: %s", str);
}
```

Comment: He wants all 5 ch. Additional loop needed.

Comment: Is this the case @fake-account ?

Comment: Recommend saving the result of `strlen` in a variable and using that as the loop condition, rather than traversing the string on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @JohanBregell as an example if the user writes "hello" and then chooses the letter "e" to be removed the result should be "hllo". I have also tried strlen but since i am trying to avoid it a the moment (for learning reasons) i want to use a different way but get the same result.

Comment: The code I wrote above will do exactly that. If you do not want to use strlen() then you will have to check str[k] != '\0' in the for loop head.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two implementations. Both remove all occurrences of the char `ch` from the string `str`

First algorithm is much faster. The second slower but easy to understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

---

```
char *removechar(char *str, int ch)
{
    char *cptr = str, *readptr = str;

    while(*readptr)
    {
        if(*readptr == ch)
        {
            readptr++;
        }
        else
        {
            *cptr++ = *readptr++;
        }
    }
    *cptr = 0;
    return str;
}
```

---

```
char *removechar(char *str, int ch)
{
    char *cpos = str;

    while((cpos = strchr(cpos, ch)))
    {
        strcpy(cpos, cpos + 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

---

```
int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello World";

    printf("%s\n", removechar(s, 'd'));
    printf("%s\n", removechar(s, 'l'));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code:

1. `str[k] != ch` would be a valid test if `ch` were indeed a character and not an array of characters of length 5. This is going to compare the character value of `str[k]` with the address `&ch[0]`.
2. `k < str` would be a valid comparison if `k` was a `char *` pointer that was initialized at `&str[0]`, not an `int` loop index starting at 0.

Corrected code:

```
int main(void) 
{
    char str[100];
    char ch[5];
    int k, j;

    printf("Write text:\n");
    //getchar();
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);

    printf("Input was: %s\n", str);

    printf("Write a character that should be removed\n");
    //getchar();
    fgets(ch, 5, stdin);

    for (k = 0, j = 0; k < strlen(str); k++)
    {
        if (str[k] != ch[0])
        {
            str[j] = str[k];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    printf("String after removing a character = %s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char str[100],c;
    printf("Write text:\n");
    fgets(str,100,stdin);
    printf("Input was: %s\n", str);
    printf("Write a character that should be removed\n");
    c=getchar();
    for(int k=0;k<strlen(str);k++){
        if(str[k]==c){
            for(int j=k;j<strlen(str);j++){
                str[j]=str[j+1];
            }
        }
    }
     printf("String after removing a character = %s", str);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: very bad algorithm.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Extremely inefficient  (you copy the whole reaming string) + many calls to strlen in the loop. Very very bad. See my answer (this with pointer) and see the difference.